# Python adding element to dict in own name

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

Is there a Python method to add/update a dict element in it's own name?

For Example:

```
error = "Some error"
response['error'] = error
```

Instead I wish

`response.push(error)`

Where the `push()` will do the above equivalent ie add `error` to `response` in the name of `'error'` itself. I have a suitable scenario to be handy than writing a huge block of code.

Comment: No, because there's no sane way to get the passed name.

Comment: Oh.. By luck, Any clues on the next steps to write such a method myself ?

Comment: It can't be done. Functions are passed values, not variable names.

Comment: I mean you COULD create your own `dict` class or hook a function that takes on argument like so `response.push("error")` and in that function you access the globals as described by Holloway. I think you're out on a slippery slope here but it's possible, just not in the way you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a nice way to do it but you could use `globals` for this.

```
>>> def updateDict(dict, value):
...     a = globals()[value]
...     dict[value] = a
... 
>>> response = {}
>>> error = "some error"
>>> updateDict(response, 'error')
>>> response
{'error': 'some error'}
```

I'd seriously consider if you need to do this though. It's not nice and I doubt it'd work too well (if at all) across modules.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when crawling a page and used classes. So in your case you could do somethin like this:

```
class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __str__(self):
        name = self.value.lower().replace(" ", "_")
        return name

error = MyError("Some error")

response = {}    

response[error.__str__()] = error.value
```

Hope it helps.